# How to include Google Place Autocomplete Address Form in Meteor V1

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete, meteor

How do I initialise googles objects to use autocomplete address form in Meteor? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

I have taken a basic approach and used the code samples provided. I have the HTTP package installed. The template has the form displaying but it is not connecting googles to the service. I am assuming the objects are not being initialised and need help to solve this issue.

```
Template.addressForm.rendered = function ({
            var placeSearch, autocomplete;
                var componentForm = {
                  street_number: 'short_name',
                  route: 'long_name',
                  locality: 'long_name',
                  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
                  country: 'long_name',
                  postal_code: 'short_name'
                };

        function initialize() {
          // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
          // to geographical location types.
          autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
              /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
              { types: ['geocode'] });
          // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
          // populate the address fields in the form.
          google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            fillInAddress();
          });
        }

        function fillInAddress() {
          // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

          for (var component in componentForm) {
            document.getElementById(component).value = '';
            document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
          }

          // Get each component of the address from the place details
          // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
          for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
              var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
              document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
            }
          }
        }

        // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
        // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
        function geolocate() {
          if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
              var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
              var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                center: geolocation,
                radius: position.coords.accuracy
              });
              autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
            });
          }
        }
        });
```

HTML:

```
           <template name="addressForm">

            <div id="locationField">
                  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
                         onFocus="geolocate()" type="text">
                </div>

                <table id="address">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label">Street address</td>
                    <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
                          disabled="true"></td>
                    <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
                          disabled="true"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label">City</td>
                    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
                          disabled="true"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label">State</td>
                    <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
                          id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></td>
                    <td class="label">Zip code</td>
                    <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
                          disabled="true"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label">Country</td>
                    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
                          id="country" disabled="true"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                </template>
```

appBody:

```
<head>
      <title>publishcity</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
          html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
          }
        </style>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to run the initialize function
in the example it's being called on the body onload hook

```
<body onload="initialize()">
```

you might have dropped it on the way

taking the code out of the function so it could run is probably all you need to make it work